# Client Side Javascript input prompt box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application: When the user presses "Search", he has to input some other value and then according to that value, some other code is run.

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearGridViewEmp();

            //Does table contain encrypted columns
            bool verifyEDT = SQLQueryAnalyser.IsTableInEDT("Employees",connectionName);

            string prompt = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
            var value = window.prompt('Input Passphrase', 'Type your passphrase here');
            storeUserInput(value);</script>";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Prompt", prompt);

            if (verifyEDT)
            {
                string passphrase = hidValue.Value;
               //do other stuff with the passphrase
            }
            FillGridViewWithEmp();
        }
```

Now the problem is that the prompt input appears AFTER all the rest of code is run and on top it completely messes up the layout of the website. I have been searching an entire day for a solution but I cannot find it. How can I show a popup input prompt box, have the user input something and then continue running some code according to the value.? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a separate AJAX call to validate the passphrase.